# SAP GUI scripting disabled on server - other automation options?

Tags: automation, scripting, sap-gui

SAP GUI scripting is disabled on my employer's servers and I'm not in a position to change that, but I would very much like to automate some routine tasks of mine using some kind of scripting. I don't have (and I don't need) administrative access to the server, so this automation [afaik] has to revolve around SAP GUI in one way or another.

As an example, most repetitive task of mine that lacks automation is loading numerous reports with different parameters and exporting them to plain text files (to be aggregated and analyzed later in Excel).

What options should I look at? Mouse-and-keyboard automation tools come to mind first, but they are the least appealing ones at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For most of the options that are available, you will need at least the cooperation of the system administrators, and usually for good reasons - automation always gives you the option of destroying vast amounts of mission-critical data very fast. Depending on what you need to do - your question was not very clear on that - you might want to explore the following options:

- Try to automate the data entry on the selection screen using [selection variants](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/c0/980374e58611d194cc00a0c94260a5/content.htm). You can not only save static sets of data, but also include dynamic date calculations, and you can reduce the fields displayed until only the relevant fields are left.
- Check whether you can [schedule background jobs](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/08703713bf277ee10000009b38f8cf/frameset.htm) to have the reports run automatically at a given time and get the contents downloaded or mailed to you, depending on the capabilities of the report in question and the settings of your system.
- For more complex flows, use the [transaction recorder](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/67/42fcd5f61011d1bcf9080009b4534c/content.htm) to check whether the task can be automated using batch input techniques. If this is possible, you could try to use the [Legacy System Migration Workbench (LSMW)](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/ad/2d54a41d7011d2b42e006094b944c8/content.htm) - although designed for data migration, you can use this tool as a "CSV-to-User-Command-Converter".
- If you've come this far, it's not that hard to start writing ABAP programs, and we're back on topic for Stack Overflow... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sikulli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to automate tasks in SAP. They have a image recognition system where it can click buttons based on what it looks like. If you need to scroll through tables or something you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous job I had to explain what SAP GUI scripting is to at least 2 dozen people and wait/follow for months to use it. Let say many people are still using my scripts there. It is always better to show your skills, So you better go proper channels. Also Using similar tools might not be welcomed If they are not enabling on their servers.